# how to check llvm version number in windows 10

Tags: windows, version, llvm

Hi i downloaded llvm using svn checkout in windows 10.
I want to know if its is properly installed or not and version number also. 
I tried to do `llvm --help` or `llvm --version` .
I am getting error

> 'llvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What's wrong and how shall I proceed?

Comment: Checking out a repo is not the same as installing a program. You have to compile that compiler first. I would suggest going back to llvm and getting a pre-compiled binary, use it from wherever you download it to or chuck that path in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

`llvm` is not the name of a command line program. LLVM comes with a bunch of developer tool. If you got the full clang distribution, you get `clang`, a C/C++/Obj-C/... compiler (command line is `clang`).
Many developer tools command line program: `opt`, `llc`, etc.
Locate the bin directory in the package you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Open `CMakeLists.txt` at the source root level. At about line 22 you'll find the code setting the version number. Read it as follows:

```
if(NOT DEFINED LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR)
  set(LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR 4)
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED LLVM_VERSION_MINOR)
  set(LLVM_VERSION_MINOR 0)
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED LLVM_VERSION_PATCH)
  set(LLVM_VERSION_PATCH 1)
```

The version number format is Major.Minor.Patch

So my version number is 4.0.1